# React-Native-Navigation lightbox position

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

I am wondering if the lightbox position from wix react native navigation can be modify its position ? I want the light box to appear at the top of the screen instead of middle . Is it possible ?

Comment: Please provide your code. What did you try to this moment?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a correct method, But anyhow I was able to overcome the issue here using StyleSheet.

```
import { StyleSheet, Dimensions } from "react-native";

.....

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginTop: 26 - Dimensions.get("window").height / 2 
  }
});
```

[image: see the image]